# the trait bound `sp_runtime::MultiSignature: Verify` is not satisfied

Tags: substrate-node-template

I get the below error when I run cargo build.
is there a code example on how to implement the missing trait or can someone point me to a detailed explanation or provide one ? thanks

```rs
    error[E0277]: the trait bound `sp_runtime::MultiSignature: Verify` is not satisfied
      --> node/src/chain_spec.rs:27:1
       |
    27 | / pub fn get_account_id_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> AccountId
    28 | | where
    29 | |     AccountPublic: From<<TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public>,
       | |_________________________________________________________^ the trait `Verify` is not implemented for `sp_runtime::MultiSignature`
       |
       = help: the following other types implement trait `Verify`:
                 AnySignature
                 MultiSignature
                 TestSignature
                 sp_core::ecdsa::Signature
                 sp_core::ed25519::Signature
                 sp_core::sr25519::Signature
    
    error[E0277]: the trait bound `sp_runtime::MultiSignature: Verify` is not satisfied
      --> node/src/chain_spec.rs:27:1
       |
    27 | / pub fn get_account_id_from_seed<TPublic: Public>(seed: &str) -> AccountId
    28 | | where
    29 | |     AccountPublic: From<<TPublic::Pair as Pair>::Public>,
    30 | | {
    31 | |     AccountPublic::from(get_from_seed::<TPublic>(seed)).into_account()
    32 | | }
       | |_^ the trait `Verify` is not implemented for `sp_runtime::MultiSignature`
       |
       = help: the following other types implement trait `Verify`:
                 AnySignature
                 MultiSignature
                 TestSignature
                 sp_core::ecdsa::Signature
                 sp_core::ed25519::Signature
                 sp_core::sr25519::Signature
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Maybe you have two different git versions of Substrate in your Cargo.lock?

Comment: Which part of the code you want to see?

Comment: That fails to compile for you.